# Add image and div inside of dropdown component

Tags: css, reactjs, drop-down-menu, semantic-ui

I am trying to customize a profile dropdown component with Semantic and React, but I am running into a couple of issues. 1. When I try to put a div inside of the Dropdown.Menu my app crashes with the error below. 2. How do I add a custom width to the actual dropdown? Right now when I hover over the dropdown it works, but I want to be able to hover over both the image or the dropdown component so the actual dropdown appears. I am trying to have this puu.sh/tM6Ly/690a02bd46.png but with an image on the side, if possible replace the dropdown arrow with the image.

```
<Dropdown simple={true} text="dropdown">
 <Dropdown.Menu>
   <Dropdown.Item>Profile 1</Dropdown.Item>
   <Dropdown.Item>Profile 2</Dropdown.Item>
   <Dropdown.Item>Profile 3</Dropdown.Item>
   <Dropdown.Item>Profile 4</Dropdown.Item>
 </Dropdown.Menu>
 <div>
   <img src="linkhidden"/>
 </div>
 </Dropdown>
```

throws the error `onlyChild must be passed a children with exactly one child.` and `Invalid prop`children`supplied to`Dropdown`, expected a single ReactElement.`

Comment: try to put the div inside `<Dropdown.Item>`

Comment: But that would add the image to the dropdown item, that's not what I am trying to do. I am trying to have this https://puu.sh/tM6Ly/690a02bd46.png but with an image on the side, if possible replace the dropdown arrow with the image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dropdown [supports](http://react.semantic-ui.com/modules/dropdown) an `icon` prop which can be used to replace the default arrow icon, as you describe is your intention in the comments. Simply pass your replacement in there.

```
<Dropdown simple={true} text="dropdown" icon={someNodeOrObject}>
 <Dropdown.Menu>
   <Dropdown.Item>Profile 1</Dropdown.Item>
   <Dropdown.Item>Profile 2</Dropdown.Item>
   <Dropdown.Item>Profile 3</Dropdown.Item>
   <Dropdown.Item>Profile 4</Dropdown.Item>
 </Dropdown.Menu>
 </Dropdown>
```

Comment: Is it possible for that icon to be a custom image? I have a link to an image on my server.

Comment: Not sure. Have you tried passing the image element you have as the icon prop?

Comment: Yea, I tried passing the img src link as the icon but I get an error `Invalid prop `name` of value supplied to `Icon`.`

Comment: You passed the url as the prop? If so i think you should try passing in an actual node, ie `icon={<img src="linkhidden"/>}`